# Typescript complex mapping between two classes

Tags: node.js, typescript

Disclaimer: First I have to say that I have a different background - Java/Scala and Typescript is definitely not my biggest strength.

I have two fairly complex classes and pre-defined contract which maps each property from class class A to class B. I have to convert instance of class A to class B and vice versa on demand. I know this could be done with a static mapper which does the translation in code, but I was wondering if there are some packages/techniques which could easy my pain. I already checked https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer, but it doesn't seem to cover everything I want.

Requirements:

1. Some array fields from one class could be transformed or flattened before mapped to the other class.
2. Class A is a simple {[key:string], string} map, while B's fields are more complex and  type inferred from the contract.
3. Key in class A might be mapped to key Y in class B.

An example A->B:

```
class A {

  "key1" = "1234"
  "key2" = "text" 
  "key3" = "10/07/2021"
  "key5" = "otherText"

}

and after conversion 

class B {

  "newKey1" = 1234,
  "newKey2" = "text",
  "newKey3" =  Date(..),
  "key4": {
      "key5": "otherText"
  }
```

Any tips, suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is this question "seeking recommendations for tools and software libraries"?

Comment: How do you plan on defining the rules?
I mean based on the complexity of the mapping depicted in your example I'd argue that the simplest approach is going to work best. That is manually create `class B`, and with some conversion helpers copy properties from instance of `class A`